# SalesForce OAuth Endpoints

Tags: rest-api, integration, oauth2, sandbox

I am working on an application, where any user can login into my application through Salesforce. As per mentioned in below url, We can use `https://login.salesforce.com` or for sandbox `https://test.salesforce.com`

```
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_oauth_endpoints.htm
```

For the authentication, and to get access token I am using `https://login.salesforce.com` but, if I also have an account on `https://test.salesforce.com` and try to login, It does not allow me as my account was registered on sandbox url, test salesforce. Now, Any type of user, We can have for the login through SalesForce, How can I achieve this thing ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take any application getting authenticated using Oauth ,you will see an application is usually provided with two different buttons .One for Login Screen from Production and other for Login from Sandbox .

Most of applications also use selector to allow user to select whether user wants to login to Production or sandbox and then initiate login call .

> Sample App that has two buttons for Login to Production and Login to Sandbox

[image]

> Sample App that provides option to select Instance first

[image]

Comment: @Mohitsh Shrivastava Thank you for your quick response. As per your answer, Do I need to provide 2 Buttons, One for Login Production, and 2nd for Login Sandbox, if You user click on Login Production, It will redirect on login.salesforce.com otherwise on test.salesforce.com for Authentication ?

Comment: Yes exactly correct :)

Comment: Ok..One more thing, I had gone through some questions like this

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/remote-access-apps-production-sandbox-support/10161#10161

Is it related to this or something different..and I have not used https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success instead of https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success if it requires to use, where do I use ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html

I have gone through this website where they are saying to use https://mysite.secure.force.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>
Now, Currently I am accessing my application through localhost..so, Is this way useful for authenticate on any url on salesforce ?

Comment: I would say you specify your webserver url as redirect URL so that once authenticated you are back on to your website .

Comment: Also please mark answer as answered if that helped

Comment: Sure, I will mark answer as accepted.
I have specified that redirect url localhost as of now. But, Once we put our application on server, we can give that server url. but, my question is that I got something from the post 

Try {siteurl}/services/oauth2/authorize as the oauth endpoint. 

so, what should I give {siteurl} over here for the localhost ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15992/discussion-between-rishabh-shah-and-mohith-shrivastava).